# Manipulating collections in Java

Tags: java, arrays, collections, linked-list

I am a beginner to programming and stuck with an homework assignment on SlidingPuzzles. the following function wants to manipulate a board, for every possible direction. What happens, is that after s got changed in one dir, that changed s is used for the next dir as well. Instead of using the original one.

```
public Collection<Configuration> successors() {
    List<Configuration> succs = new LinkedList<>();
    SlidingGame t = new SlidingGame(this.board);
    for (Direction dir : Direction.values()) {
        if (t.canMove(dir)) {  
            SlidingGame s = new SlidingGame(this.board);
            s.holeX = t.holeX+dir.getDX();
            s.holeY = t.holeY+dir.getDY();
            s.board[t.holeX][t.holeY] = t.board[s.holeX][s.holeY];
            s.board[s.holeX][s.holeY] = HOLE;
            succs.add(s);
        }
    }
    return succs;
}
```

even t changes, which i do not manipulate at all. 
this is the constructor used:

```
public SlidingGame(int[][] board){
    this.board = board;
    for(int i = 0; i < N ; i++){
        for(int j = 0 ; j < N; j++){
            if(board[i][j] == HOLE){
                holeX = i;
                holeY = j;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sorry for the noob question, but I'm stuck for quite some time now. Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you pass a reference (i.e. this.board) you share the same (array) object into two objects of class SlidingGame. See java.util.Arrays.copyOf. But take care: the elements of board are array references, too!

Comment: All your SlidingGame objects access the same array.

Comment: Probably the task (whatever it ultimately is) can be done in a much simpler way without creating a new instance of SlidingGame for each move.

Comment: how can I create an Object than, which is created by the same array, but does not get manipulated along the way? An Array 'copy' that I made with copyOf is also unwanted manipulated now. We have to use BFS to find the solution, therefore i thought, stacking slidinggames on a list would be  good idea?